# crash when integrate PayMob sdk

Tags: android

paymob is sdk for payment , and i integrate it in may project but when i launch PayActivity in sdk my app crash and display this error
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.democompany.paymobapplication/com.paymob.acceptsdk.PayActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050034 type #0x1 is not valid

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050034 type #0x1 is not valid
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
```

UPDATE :-
i Search inside PayActivity inside paymob sdk and i found this code inside onCreate method of activity
this.themeColor = intent.getIntExtra("theme_color", this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(color.colorPrimaryDark));

Comment: Your app or the SDK is trying to access a resource (probably a Color Int) which not valid. Please post some relevant code as well.

Comment: i search inside PayActivity of paymob sdk and i found this 
 this.themeColor = intent.getIntExtra("theme_color", this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(color.colorPrimaryDark)); 
- @DarShan